# FreeBSD 9 and Windows 7 Dual Boot

Tags: freebsd, dual-boot

I have two hard drives installed on my machine. I installed Windows 7 on one hard drive and FreeBSD 9 on the other. I used GPT for FreeBSD. My question is: how can I install a boot manager so that I can dual boot? (In FreeBSD 8, `sysinstall` asks for a boot manager but `bsdinstall` doesn't?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was talking to FreeBSD people and they posted a HOWTO on how to do the dual boot.

[Simple dual-boot Windows and FreeBSD 9 under MBR](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=28925)

Other useful links:

[How To: Dual Boot Windows 7 and FreeBSD](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=28436)

[How to install grub2 on FreeBSD](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=28443)

Answer (score 3):

You can use also this guide for [dual-booting Windows 7 and Unix](http://www.boyans.net/DualBootWindows7andLinuxOrUnix.html) descendants like FreeBSD.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the [boot0cfg(8)](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/8/boot0cfg/) manpage .